# sorting list of list w.r.t another list of lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting

I have two list of lists, where i want to sort the first with respect to the second. For example here i have the two

```
old = [[1, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 0, 8, 9], 
       [7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 8, 0, 9], 
       [9, 2, 8, 7, 1, 5, 0, 4, 6, 3]]
new = [[4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 8, 2, 3, 0], 
       [10, 6, 4, 3, 0, 11, 2, 5, 8, 1, 9, 7], 
       [0, 1, 7, 10, 9, 6, 4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 11]]
```

I want to sort the `new` list of list w.r.t the `old` list of list. so for the new one the entries should become

```
sorted_new = [[1, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11], 
              [7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 8, 0, 9, 10, 11], 
              [9, 2, 8, 7, 1, 5, 0, 4, 6, 3, 10, 11]]
```

important to note is both lists that are to be matched are not of equal size. how can I achieve this?

Comment: But it is not really clear to me what you mean with "with respect to another list". Especially since the lists are not of equal size. Can you explain how the input maps on the output?

Comment: Based on you example you do not sort the list, you simply append the list `new` with elements of `old` that were not in the list yet.

Comment: To me this question is completely unclear. It seems the "sorted new" is not sorted at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
sorted_new = []
for sub_new,sub_old in zip(new,old):
    old_idx = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(sub_old)}
    sorted_new.append(sorted(sub_new,key=lambda x:old_idx.get(x,len(sub_old))))
```

This then generates:

```
>>> sorted_new
[[1, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11], [7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 8, 0, 9, 10, 11], [9, 2, 8, 7, 1, 5, 0, 4, 6, 3, 10, 11]]
```

The code works as follows: we first run over the two lists `new` and `old` concurrently. For every such pair of lists. We first generate a dictionary, with *dictionary comprehension*, that maps the elements of the `sub_old` to their corresponding indices in the list.

Next we construct a sorted list for `sub_new`. If the element of that `sub_new` is in the `old_idx`, we return the index (and this is thus the sorting key). If not, we return a default `len(sub_old)`, which is thus greater than all the indices in the dictionary. As a result that element will be placed at the right of the list.

Since Python's sort function is guaranteed to be *stable* that means that the elements that were not in `old`, will maintain the original order.

We could have used some magic around the `list.index(..)` method, instead of constructing such index dictionary. But the problem with `.index(..)` is that it runs in *O(n)*. So this would make the algorithm *O(m×n log n)* for every sublist, with *m* the number of elements in `old`, and *n* the number of elements in `new`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot :)